# Search JSON for multiple values, not using a library

Tags: json, search

I'd like to be able to search the following JSON object for objects containing the key 'location' then get in return an array or json object with the 'name' of the person plus the value of location for that person.

Sample return:

> var matchesFound = [{Tom Brady, New York}, {Donald Steven,Los Angeles}];

```
var fbData0 = {
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "X999_Y999",
         "location": "New York",
         "from": {
            "name": "Tom Brady", "id": "X12"
         },
         "message": "Looking forward to 2010!",
         "actions": [
            {
               "name": "Comment",
               "link": "http://www.facebook.com/X999/posts/Y999"
            },
            {
               "name": "Like",
               "link": "http://www.facebook.com/X999/posts/Y999"
            }
         ],
         "type": "status",
         "created_time": "2010-08-02T21:27:44+0000",
         "updated_time": "2010-08-02T21:27:44+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "X998_Y998",
         "location": "Los Angeles",
         "from": {
            "name": "Donald Steven", "id": "X18"
         },
         "message": "Where's my contract?",
         "actions": [
            {
               "name": "Comment",
               "link": "http://www.facebook.com/X998/posts/Y998"
            },
            {
               "name": "Like",
               "link": "http://www.facebook.com/X998/posts/Y998"
            }
         ],
         "type": "status",
         "created_time": "2010-08-02T21:27:44+0000",
         "updated_time": "2010-08-02T21:27:44+0000"
      }
   ]
};
```

Comment: Which library are you using for JSON parsing?

Comment: With respect to the current JSON do you want your result to be [{Tom Brady,New York},{Donald Steven,Los Angeles}]

Comment: I edited the return for clarity. I wanted an array of objects (primary). I am not currently using a library but vanilla JS or YUI is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

@vsiege - you can use this javascript lib (http://www.defiantjs.com/) to search your JSON structure.

```
var fbData0 = {
   ...
},
res = JSON.search( fbData0, '//*[./location and ./from/name]' ),
str = '';

for (var i=0; i<res.length; i++) {
    str += res[i].location +': '+ res[i].from.name +'<br/>';
}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = str;
```

Here is a working fiddle;
http://jsfiddle.net/hbi99/XhRLP/

DefiantJS extends the global object JSON with the method "search" and makes it possible to query JSON with XPath expressions (XPath is standardised query language). The method returns an array with the matches (empty array if none were found).

You can test XPath expressions by pasting your JSON here:
http://www.defiantjs.com/#xpath_evaluator

Comment: I will look into this lib. Thank your for the response. I would still like to see how this is done without the use of a library (as to not throw off those looking into this thread based on the title).

Comment: vsiege - I've edited m previous answer and completed it with a fiddle (as a POC). Let me know if you want me to clarify anything. The sourcecode of Defiant is available on Github